# SELECT from single table, conditional count(*) with empty resultset should be displayed

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by, where-clause

This question has been asked in different fashions a hundred times here, but none of them helped with my example:

One single table: mytable

```
+-------+-------+
| feld1 | feld2 |
+-------+-------+
| Hugo  | 5     |
| Anna  | 5     |
| Anna  | 5     |
| Otto  | 6     |
+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want the following result:

```
Hugo 1
Anna 2
Otto 0
```

which is the distinct feld1 entries followed by the number of entries with feld2=5

With

```
SELECT DISTINCT feld1, count(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE feld2=5
GROUP BY feld1
```

I get

```
Hugo 1
Anna 2
```

I read to use LEFT JOIN to solve my problem, but I don't get a working solution.

What I tried besides many, many others without success:

```
SELECT e.feld1, count(*) FROM mytable as e 
       LEFT JOIN mytable as f 
              ON e.feld1 = f.feld1 
WHERE f.feld2=5
GROUP BY e.feld1
```

I also tried many things I read, such as using IS NULL or IFNULL or COALESCE...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE to convert your feld2 value to either a 1 or 0 and then sum them up.  Like this:

```
select feld1, sum(case feld2 when 5 then 1 else 0 end) from mytable group by feld1;
```

Result:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+
| feld1 | sum(case feld2 when 5 then 1 else 0 end) |
+-------+------------------------------------------+
| Anna  |                                        2 |
| Hugo  |                                        1 |
| Otto  |                                        0 |
+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: this works and looks pretty easy! :-) not sure, but i, i expect the use of this sum function to be slower than using count, isn't it? is there another solution to my problem using the count, join version?

Comment: I'd wager that the performance difference is quite small.  The problem with count is that you can't count records that are excluded from your set.  So no, I don't think there is a way to do that (but if someone wants to prove me wrong I'd be glad to know how it is done as well).

Comment: I removed the accepted solution for the moment so others feel invited to clear up that it is definitely not possible. i understood from other topics that by doing a join (which should also be possible with a single table on itself as i read somewhere) i could map the reduced set to the full set of feld1 entries.

Comment: (gotcha - i would suggest upvoting helpful posts in any case, regardless of which one is accepted answer)

Comment: of course, i'd like to do that, but i do not have enough reputation yet to do so... :-(

Answer (score 0):

The query compiler might be getting confused by your lack of naming a table to perform the count on. So explicitly naming which field and from which table you want the count to be performed on could do the trick.

```
SELECT   e.feld1, count(f.feld1)
FROM     mytable as e 
           LEFT JOIN mytable as f 
              ON e.feld1 = f.feld1 
WHERE    f.feld2=5
GROUP BY e.feld1
```

Alternatively, if the above still doesn't work because the query optimizer is removing the outer join due to it seeing some kind of null-rejected case you can use a subquery as I've listed below. This will filter the results before the join operation is pushed through the query optimizer.

```
SELECT   e.feld1, count(f.feld1)
FROM     mytable as e 
           LEFT JOIN (select i.feld1 from mytable as i where i.feld2=5) as f 
              ON e.feld1 = f.feld1
GROUP BY e.feld1
```

Edited to change the count to the values from 'f'

Comment: your solution 1 gives me "Anna,4 Hugo,1"... solution 2 gives me "Anna,4 Hugo,1 Otto,1"... :-/

Comment: Sorry, should have been counting the items returned by 'f' not 'e' since we're interested in what exists in the filtered elements. Counting 'e' will give us everything from 'e' since it is the full set in the consideration of the outer join. Not sure why Anna was doubled and hugo was not though. Is that still the case?

Comment: The second still does not work fully correctly.  It delivers "Anna 4, Hugo 1, Otto 0" (Anna still doubled) For my real table consisting of 1.2 million rows I get a timeout running that query. You get an upvote as soon as I am able to do so though.